# Refresh Header in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments

Though i have been looking around, couldn't find the correct answer.
In my navigation drawer header I provide user with his image and name, But i also allow the user to change his/her name and image from the app. 
These changes are stored in session manager. 
Now i want to reflect these changes in my navigation drawer header.
Everything is working fine because when i close the app and run it again it shows the changes.
So for now what i need is a way to refresh the navigation drawer header.

Select image from gallery in Profile Fragment.

```
 private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {

        String selectedImagePath = getPathFromCameraData(data, getActivity());

        Bitmap bm;
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 200;
        int scale = 1;
        while (options.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE
                && options.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
            scale *= 2;
        options.inSampleSize = scale;
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);
        bitmap = bm;
        profilephoto = BitMapToString(bm);

        session.setprofilepic(profilephoto);// make changes in session.
          profilepic.setImageBitmap(bm);

    }
```

Homepage activity

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_homepageactivity);
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        topToolBar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(topToolBar);
        //topToolBar.setLogo(R.drawable.logo);
        topToolBar.setLogoDescription(getResources().getString(R.string.logo_desc));


        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        listHeaderView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header_list, null, false);

        //ImageView profile = (ImageView)listHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.profile_picture);

        TextView name = (TextView)listHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.headername);
        profilepic = (ImageView)listHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.profile);

        user = session.getUserDetails();
        profilepic.setImageBitmap(StringToBitMap(user.get(SessionManager.KEY_PROFILEPIC)));
        name.setText(user.get(SessionManager.KEY_NAME));
        mDrawerList.addHeaderView(listHeaderView); ////// HEADER ADDED


        List<ItemObject> listViewItems = new ArrayList<ItemObject>();
       listViewItems.add(new ItemObject("Attendance", R.drawable.attendance));
      //  listViewItems.add(new ItemObject("Time table", R.drawable.timetable));
       // listViewItems.add(new ItemObject("Class 1", R.drawable.classicon));

        adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, listViewItems);


        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, listViewItems));

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(Homepageactivity.this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                profilepic.setImageBitmap(StringToBitMap(user.get(SessionManager.KEY_PROFILEPIC)));
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // make Toast when click
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                selectItemFragment(position);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Rishabh, have you resolved your problem? If yes then please post your solution (line of code)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Though I am really sorry for posting the answer this late.
I resolved my problem by refreshing the header whenever I open the drawer or we can when onDrawerOpened is called.

```
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(Homepageactivity.this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
            user = session.getUserDetails();
            profilepic.setImageBitmap(StringToBitMap(user.get(SessionManager.KEY_PROFILEPIC)));
            name.setText(user.get(SessionManager.KEY_NAME));
            lastsynced.setText(lastsynced());
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
```

Comment: To reliably update a `TextView` in a navigation drawer header, it seems to be necessary to retrieve all the references again in the [`ActionBarDrawerToggle.onDrawerOpened()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html#onDrawerOpened(android.view.View)) method. I combined your answer with this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45520466/1657502.

Comment: I said that because you are using `profilepic` in `onDrawerOpened()`, but you defined it in `onCreate()`. That didn't work for me. Making an analogy with your case, I needed to retrieve `profilepic` again in `onDrawerOpened()`.

Answer (score 0):

It's been years since the question was asked but if you find your way to this answer, my solution is as follows

```
drawer.addDrawerListener( new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
        if(newState == 2){
            // do your things here
        }
    }

    // ...
    // several other override functions

});
```

The newState 2 means "drawer about to move" afaik, both open and close.
This way users won't see the changing process as you alter the content of the drawer, unlike the onDrawerOpened approach. But you may want to utilize the onDrawerOpened method to check the actual state of the drawer.