# Updating TextView in NavigationView Header

Tags: android

I have a activity_main.xml with a NavigationView like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_drawer"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/colorAccent"
    />
```

I have a header layout and there is a textview there. I was wondering how I can access that textview? I have code in my main activity which will update that textview but I am unsure how to have access to that textview. The header.xml is not part of an activity.

In my main activity I have this piece of code:

```
public void checkCurrentUser() {
    ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    if (user != null) {
        nameOfCurrentUser.setText(user.getUsername());
    }
}
```

which will update that textview with the current user's username

Comment: See this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33161345/android-support-v23-1-0-update-breaks-navigationview-get-find-header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33161345/android-support-v23-1-0-update-breaks-navigationview-get-find-header)

Answer (score 3):

You have to take the view object and find the element,

Java

```
 View headerLayout = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    useremail = (TextView) headerLayout.findViewById(R.id.tv_useremail);
```

XML

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer" />
```

Comment: To reliably update a `TextView` in a navigation drawer header, use this code in the [`ActionBarDrawerToggle.onDrawerOpened()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html#onDrawerOpened(android.view.View)) method. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35952939/1657502.

Answer (score 0):

header is called by xml.
so u can simply use:

```
TextView nameOfCurrentUser = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.YOURTEXTVIEWINHEADER);nameOfCurrentUser.setText(user.getUsername());
```

Comment: cant do that. i cant access elements in my header xml from my main xml

Comment: you can access to elements from "main activity".