# how to connect nav_header_main?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I want to change the textview, email which are in nav_header by OnCreate, but i get the error **On a null object reference**.

[image: Picture 1]
[image: Picture 2]

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                  at multimedia.slidemenu.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34973456/how-to-change-text-of-a-textview-in-navigation-drawer-header
   check this link please, and try it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

thanks  *Melicias*, it works for me using this code :

```
NavigationView navigationView= (NavigationView) findViewById (R.id.navigationView);    
View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
```

And then I can set the text like this:

```
TextView text = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText("xxxxx");
```