# How to change image and text of header NavigationView

Tags: android, header, navigationview

I wanted to change the name and image of the header to the username of the people who are currently logged in but no idea how to do it I'm new to android studio and don't know how this works, i also tried to find the
[@string/nav_header_subtitle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9eyV.png) and i can't find it anywhere can anyone help me?

Edit:

This is the main activity

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity

    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener();

    NavigationView  navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_profile) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_balance) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_setting) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_help) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {

            final ProgressDialog dlg = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            ParseUser.logOut();
            moveTaskToBack(true);
            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
            System.exit(1);

        }
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;

      }
   }
```

Where should I put the code in there?

Edit: I did the codes below and  [this showed up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AN1fc.png)

Edit:
Header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/nav_header_desc"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_namedisplay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:text="@string/nav_header_title"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/nav_header_subtitle" />
```

Comment: Then post source code of your java class too so we can find your mistake.

Comment: for left side navigator, the layout is in drawer, please find the drawer layout file and edit.

Comment: Please check out my solution below, With explanation.

Comment: clear and ReBuild your project for Cannot resolve symbol

Comment: Please show me your Header xml code, I'll give you the exact solution. (Copy Paste in your question, Do not paste it as an image). Thanks

Comment: I changed the red colored Cannot resolve errors with the names of the header and there is still problem in the HeaderName.username(Your_name_string);

Comment: @Euxicius `Your_name_string` is whatever string you want to display.. like title and description.. Check my edited answer.

Comment: @Euxicius Did it work now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change text of a TextView in navigation drawer header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34973456/how-to-change-text-of-a-textview-in-navigation-drawer-header)

Comment: I tried messing with it for hours now but i dont really get it there are still red lines and when i try to change it more the more reds appear

Comment: @Euxicius did you try clean and rebuild project?

Answer (score 2):

Change your main activity to something like this:

```
TextView username, mailusernave; 
ImageView imageUser;
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
username = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.usernamenav);
mailusernave = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.mailnav);
imageUser = (ImageView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.imgUser);
username.setText("name")
```

Answer (score 0):

First define TextView and ImageView in your NavigationView header
then do this in your Java code

```
NavigationView  navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
View            HeaderView= navigationView.getHeaderView(0);         
TextView        TextHeaderTitle = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.txt_namedisplay);
TextView        TextHeaderSubTitle = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.txt_namedisplay);
ImageView       ImageUser = (ImageView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

TextHeaderTitle.setText("TITLE TEXT");
TextHeaderSubTitle .setText("SUB TITLE TEXT");
ImageHeaderNav.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_user);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

You can get the `HeaderView` from the `NavigationView` object like this:

```
NavigationView  navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
```

Then,

```
TextView HeaderName = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.txt_namedisplay);
TextView HeaderEmail = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.textView);
ImageView imgHeaderLogo = (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

Then, get the String which you want to display:

```
String title = "Your_Title_String";
String desc = "Your_Description_String";
String image = "Your_base64_Image";

HeaderName.setText(title);
HeaderEmail.setText(desc);
```

Then, For Profile image, (if you have BASE64 String), Use:

```
byte[] image = Base64.decode(image, Base64.DEFAULT);
int i = image.length;
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
imgHeaderLogo.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Use all this inside your `onCreate()`

That's it..

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried using your codes and have problems with Cannot resolve symbol 'imgProfileimage' / 'lblHeaderName' / 'lblHeaderEmail' and in the HeaderName.username(Your_name_string);
HeaderEmail.setText(Your_Email_String);
I totally hve no idea what to do

Comment: Can you show me your code so that I'll assist you further.. This is a working example of my own project. @Euxicius

Comment: friendly are good.but here we search for solution and there are a main rule for answering in this site  that just created for help people spend less time for find good and clear answer , and friendly not one of that rule !

Comment: I edited above the image on what happen when i put it in the main

Comment: @Euxicius In the place of red colored Cannot resolve, you must write your own xml ids

Comment: Okay @AliKhaki Thanks. But, that's my way of writing.