# How to set nav_header username and picture

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, navigation-drawer

I want to set User name and picture when new user sign in. I already have tried to use findViewById() but when i set values "navHeaderName.setText(user_name);" it gave me null pointer exception .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change text of a TextView in navigation drawer header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34973456/how-to-change-text-of-a-textview-in-navigation-drawer-header)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use findViewById in your Activity, not in fragment.