# Why findViewById() return null for a view in a drawer header?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have a `DrawerLayout` which wraps a `NavigationView` with a header layout. The XML is below:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The `headerLayout` is a `LinearLayout` which wraps a `ImageView`, below is `drawer_header.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/blue_primary"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:id="@+id/ivDrawerUserFace"
        android:layout_height="120dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I don't know why I can't find the `ImageView` by `findViewById(R.id.ivDrawerUserFace)`, which returns `null` instead. However, I am able to find it by the following code:

```
ViewGroup headerView = (ViewGroup) mNavigationView.getHeaderView(0);
ImageView faceView = (ImageView) headerView.getChildAt(0); // faceView is not null
String faceUrl = QingUApp.getInstance().getFaceUrl();
if (faceUrl != null) {
     Glide.with(this).load(faceUrl).into(faceView);
}
View viewById = findViewById(R.id.ivDrawerUserFace); // viewById is null
```

I have called `setContentView()` before the above code. And `Glide` loads the image into the `ImageView` successfully. Why can't I find it by `findViewById()`?

I guess it's because the image view isn't within the XML file passed to `setContentView()`. However, I could get the view by `findViewById()` in the same `Activity` with code like this:

```
private LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Bitmap> mUserFaceLoaderCallbacks = new LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Bitmap>() {
    @Override
    public Loader<Bitmap> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        return new UserFaceLoader(NewQingUActivity.this, mFaceUrl);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Bitmap> loader, Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (bitmap != null) {
            ImageView ivUserFace = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivDrawerUserFace);
            ivUserFace.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Bitmap> loader) {

    }
};
```

Comment: Did you fix it? :D

Comment: @Vucko I didn't :)

Comment: Just to clarify, did you set the content view (ie. `setContentView()`) before try to get the view?

Answer (score 7):

when you are using navigation view in higher version like **compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'** you have to implement your view as below:

```
View parentView = your_navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
TextView text = (TextView)parentView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

Comment: To reliably update a `TextView` in a navigation drawer header, it seems to be necessary to retrieve all the references again in the [`ActionBarDrawerToggle.onDrawerOpened()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html#onDrawerOpened(android.view.View)) method. I combined your answer with this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35952939/1657502.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem. Instead of:

`View viewById = findViewById(R.id.ivDrawerUserFace);`

Maybe try:

```
View parentView = findViewById(R.id.ID_OF_PARENT_LINEAR_LAYOUT);
View viewById = parentView.findViewById(R.id.ivDrawerUserFace);
```

Just add the id for the linear layout which contains this view and replace

> ID_OF_PARENT_LINEAR_LAYOUT

with it.