# Auto refresh navigation drawer header

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

When I edit profile pic and it saved it properly in the fragment, but I have to find the way to **get the nav header profile pic** to update the profile picture same as my fragment. I need an auto refresher the profile picture in the navigation header when the navigation drawer is open. I have found 1 reference, but there is not a clear program and explanation.

[Refresh Header in Navigation Drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32806735/refresh-header-in-navigation-drawer)

Layout images-issue that happening

[image]

ProfileFragment.java

```
package com.example.imlproject.ui.admin_profile;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.Image;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;

import com.example.imlproject.Admin_Activity;
import com.example.imlproject.R;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.OnProgressListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImage;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView;

import java.util.UUID;

import static android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK;


public
class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

    private ProfileViewModel profileViewModel;
    private TextView companyName,companyRegisterNumber,email,ic;
    private EditText address,username,description,businessHour,contact;
    private ImageView profile_pic,admin_edit_profile_pic,admin_save_profile_pic;
    private FrameLayout frameLayout1;
    private String imageURL;
    private FirebaseStorage storage;
    private StorageReference storageReference;
    private DatabaseReference reference;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private FirebaseUser user;
    View headview;
    ImageView nav_admin_profile_pic;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    private static final int GalleryPick  = 1;
    Uri filePath;

    public
    View onCreateView (
            @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater ,
            ViewGroup container , Bundle savedInstanceState
                      ) {
        profileViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of ( this ).get ( ProfileViewModel.class );
        final View           root     = inflater.inflate ( R.layout.fragment_admin_profile , container , false );

        profile_pic=(ImageView )root.findViewById(R.id.admin_profile_fragment_profile_pic) ;
        admin_edit_profile_pic=(ImageView)root.findViewById(R.id.admin_profile_image_edit_icon) ;
        admin_save_profile_pic=(ImageView )root.findViewById(R.id.admin_profile_image_save_icon) ;

        address=(EditText )root.findViewById(R.id.admin_profile_fragment_address_textView);
        businessHour=(EditText )root.findViewById(R.id.admin_profile_fragment_business_hour_textView);
        contact=(EditText )root.findViewById(R.id.admin_profile_fragment_contact_textView);
        description=(EditText )root.findViewById(R.id.admin_profile_fragment_description_textView);
        username=(EditText )root.findViewById(R.id.admin_profile_fragment_username_textView);

        companyName=(TextView )root.findViewById(R.id.admin_profile_fragment_company_name_textView);
        companyRegisterNumber=(TextView )root.findViewById(R.id.admin_profile_fragment_company_register_number_textView);
        email=(TextView )root.findViewById(R.id.admin_profile_fragment_email_textView);
        ic=(TextView )root.findViewById(R.id.admin_profile_fragment_ic_textView);





        frameLayout1 = (FrameLayout )root.findViewById(R.id.FrameLayout1);
        profile_pic.setEnabled(false);



        storage=FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        storageReference=storage.getReference();
        auth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        user=auth.getCurrentUser();
        reference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Account").child(user.getUid());

        //============================================================================================================================================================================
        profile_pic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){

                CropImage.activity()
                        .setAspectRatio(1,1)
                        .setCropShape(CropImageView.CropShape.RECTANGLE)
                        .start(getContext(),ProfileFragment.this);

            }
        });
        //============================================================================================================================================================================

        //============================================================================================================================================================================
        admin_edit_profile_pic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                admin_edit_profile_pic.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                admin_save_profile_pic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                frameLayout1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                profile_pic.setEnabled(true);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Click your profile image above to edit it",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        //============================================================================================================================================================================

        //============================================================================================================================================================================
        admin_save_profile_pic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){


                uploadImage();
                admin_edit_profile_pic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                admin_save_profile_pic.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                frameLayout1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                profile_pic.setEnabled(false);


            }
        });
        //============================================================================================================================================================================


        //============================================================================================================================================================================
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
                address.setText(dataSnapshot.child("address").getValue().toString());
                businessHour.setText(dataSnapshot.child("businessHour").getValue().toString());
                companyName.setText(dataSnapshot.child("companyName").getValue().toString());
                companyRegisterNumber.setText(dataSnapshot.child("companyRegisterNumber").getValue().toString());
                contact.setText(dataSnapshot.child("contact").getValue().toString());
                description.setText(dataSnapshot.child("description").getValue().toString());
                email.setText(dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue().toString());
                ic.setText(dataSnapshot.child("ic").getValue().toString());
                username.setText(dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue().toString());

                imageURL=dataSnapshot.child("imageURL").getValue().toString();

                StorageReference ref=FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(imageURL);

                ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>(){
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri){

                        Picasso.get().load(uri).resize(250,250).into(profile_pic);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Image Loaded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),databaseError.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        //============================================================================================================================================================================
        return root;
    }


    //============================================================================================================================================================================
    private void uploadImage()
    {
        if(filePath!=null)
        {
            String imageid=UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            StorageReference ref =storageReference.child("images/"+imageid);
            ref.putFile(filePath)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Upload to online storage Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    });
            auth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            user=auth.getCurrentUser();
            reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Account").child(user.getUid());
            reference.child("imageURL").setValue("gs://iml-project-4ccff.appspot.com/images/"+imageid);


            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Profile image saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //============================================================================================================================================================================
            //View headerView = root.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_admin_);
            //nav_admin_profile_pic=(ImageView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.admin_nav_imageView);
           /* reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){

                    imageURL=dataSnapshot.child("imageURL").getValue().toString();

                    StorageReference ref=FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(imageURL);

                    ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>(){
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri){

                            Picasso.get().load(uri).resize(250,250).into(nav_admin_profile_pic);
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Image Loaded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),databaseError.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });*/
            //============================================================================================================================================================================
        }
    }
    //============================================================================================================================================================================


    //============================================================================================================================================================================
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK ) {
                Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
                filePath = result.getUri();
                profile_pic.setImageURI(resultUri);
            } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
                Exception error = result.getError();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }


    }
    //============================================================================================================================================================================

}
```

Admin.Activity.java

```
package com.example.imlproject;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Admin_Activity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    ImageView nav_admin_profile_pic;
    TextView nav_admin_username, nav_admin_email;
    View headview;
    String imageURL;
    //============================================================================================================================================================================
    FirebaseStorage storage;
    StorageReference storageReference;
    DatabaseReference reference;
    FirebaseAuth auth;
    FirebaseUser user;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    //============================================================================================================================================================================

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_);

        storage=FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        storageReference=storage.getReference();

        Toolbar toolbar=findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        final DrawerLayout drawer=findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView=findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration=new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(R.id.nav_admin_profile,R.id.nav_admin_upload_product,R.id.nav_admin_edit_product,R.id.nav_admin_delete_product,R.id.nav_admin_order_receive,R.id.nav_admin_unpaid_order,R.id.nav_admin_history).setDrawerLayout(drawer).build();
        NavController navController=Navigation.findNavController(this,R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this,navController,mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView,navController);

        headview=navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        nav_admin_profile_pic=headview.findViewById(R.id.admin_nav_imageView);
        nav_admin_username=headview.findViewById(R.id.admin_nav_username);
        nav_admin_email=headview.findViewById(R.id.admin_nav_email);
        auth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        user=auth.getCurrentUser();
        reference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Account").child(user.getUid());

        //============================================================================================================================================================================
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
                nav_admin_email.setText(dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue().toString());
                nav_admin_username.setText(dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue().toString());
                imageURL=dataSnapshot.child("imageURL").getValue().toString();

                StorageReference ref=FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(imageURL);

                ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>(){
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri){

                        Picasso.get().load(uri).resize(250,250).into(nav_admin_profile_pic);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Image Loaded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),databaseError.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        //============================================================================================================================================================================


    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.admin_,menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.admin_logout:{
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(Admin_Activity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Warning!!!");
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to logout your account?");
            builder.setCancelable(true);
            //============================================================================================================================================================================
            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which){
                    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                    Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),login_activity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            });
            //============================================================================================================================================================================
            builder.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which){
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            //============================================================================================================================================================================
            AlertDialog alertDialog=builder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
            break;
        }

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp(){
        NavController navController=Navigation.findNavController(this,R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController,mAppBarConfiguration)||super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(Admin_Activity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Warning!!!");
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to logout your account?");
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        //============================================================================================================================================================================
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which){
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),login_activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
        //============================================================================================================================================================================
        builder.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which){
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        //============================================================================================================================================================================
        AlertDialog alertDialog=builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

    }


}
```

nav_header_admin_.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/admin_nav_imageView"
        android:layout_width="250px"
        android:layout_height="250px"
        android:contentDescription="@string/nav_header_desc"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/admin_nav_username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="username"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/admin_nav_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="email" />

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_admin_.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_admin_"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_admin_"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_admin__drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: You may need add more detail explanation for the problem you met. The message you provided seems a little confused.

Comment: Put your code, please. So it's easy for us to fix.

Comment: Code updated  and more detailed

Comment: Isn't that commented block code in ProfileFragment.java work?

Comment: @FahryMohammed it was not working. I dont know how to implemement this line >> View headerView = root.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_admin_);

Comment: @PhangK.A Did you try my answer? Don't hesitate to ask if you have any doubts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference the navigation view's attribute in the fragment. So do the following changes in your ProfileFragment.java firebase listener.

```
ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>(){
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri){


                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Image Loaded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    //declare a global variable to contain the uri to 
                    //set in the drawable listener
                    globalDeclaredUri = uri;

                }
            });
```

ProfileFragment.java onCreate should be listening to the drawer activities.
Make sure the getActivity is not null.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_);

    storage=FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    storageReference=storage.getReference();

    //your codes continues...

   NavigationView navigationView =(NavigationView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
   View parentView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
   ImageView navProfilePic = parentView.findViewById(R.id.admin_nav_imageView);

   DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);                    

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    final View parentView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    final ImageView navProfilePic = parentView.findViewById(R.id.img_header_bg);

    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
            Picasso.get()
                       .load(globalDeclaredUri)
                       .resize(250,250)
                       .into(navProfilePic);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the problem solved. But there is some problem that occurs with my firebase. I will post a new question regarding my problem because it is very weird for me

Comment: If it solved, please make as accepted answer. Try to use OOP and architecture patterns as you can. it will help you to more abstract and to do the clean code.